# Python How to merge 3 images into a default background image and save as new image?

Tags: python, image, merge

I am trying to use python to merge images automatically and send the result to printer.

I learning python by doing this thing, but I cannot go to the next step now.

I'll use the Raspberry Pi to run it and I will make the Pi as a local sever to handle the images that be uploaded by users.

I want to merge images like this

[image]

After lots of searched I got some code to do it but always with error.

```
import os
from PIL import Image

images = [f for f in os.listdir('path')]

result = Image.open('/mydir/bg.jpg')
result.paste(Image.open(images[0],(133,106)
result.paste(Image.open(images[1],(881,106)
result.paste(Image.open(images[2],(1629,106)
result.save('path'+'.jpg')
```

I merge some code to get this one. I know it isn't right but I try my best.

I can get what I want by use specific filename. Now I guess images be read as sting in list so that Image.open cannot open file correctly.

**My real goal is list the files in the upload folder and merge them with the default background image to create a new image which could be print.**

Maybe you have some better idea, please tell me. I'll be really grateful to your help.

Comment: What is the exact error you are receiving?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you miss closing parentheses in the following lines:

```py
result.paste(Image.open(images[0]),(133,106))
result.paste(Image.open(images[1]),(881,106))
result.paste(Image.open(images[2]),(1629,106))
```

**Updated:**

The full solution follows.

```
import os
from PIL import Image

bg_path = './bg.jpg'
fg_path = './fg'

images = [os.path.join(fg_path, name) for name in os.listdir(fg_path) if name.endswith('.jpg')]

result = Image.open(bg_path)
result.paste(Image.open(images[0]),(133,106))
result.paste(Image.open(images[1]),(881,106))
result.paste(Image.open(images[2]),(1629,106))
result.save('{}.jpg'.format(fg_path))
```

Comment: the error shows me is `fb =  builtins.open(fp, 'rb')`. I don't know what is that means. I got inspired by these two code [link](https://gist.github.com/glombard/7cd166e311992a828675) [link](http://codekea.com/5B7jlZ9kqAOo/put-series-of-images-into-one-a4-pages-using-python.html)

Comment: @MonSwag, are you sure that `/mydir/bg.jpg` file exists? It is an absolute path from the root. Maybe you want to refer to `./mydir/bg.jpg` (relative to current directory) or `~/mydir/bg.jpg` (relative to home directory)? Also `os.listdir()` lists only names w/o directory. You need to call `os.path.join('path', f)` to obtain the full path.

Comment: You are right. I use full path in my code. I use `/mydir/bg.jpg` as a sample here. And if I use specific fiename in list `images = ['/images/1.jpg', 'images/2.jpg']` ,code will runs without error and the result image is what I want. But I want the code finish my job when I don't know the name of image .

Comment: @MonSwag I've updated my answer with the full program source. It contains all corrections and works  for me :)

Comment: Thank you so much! You are awesome! And one more thing, is `fg_path`  means the folder holds images, am I right?

Comment: @MonSwag Yes, exactly. If you like the answer please vote for it and mark it as an accepted solution here on stackoverflow :)